# How to serve non-root static files by nginx?

Tags: nginx

I tried:

```
user nginx;
...
...
       location / {
           root /home/tango/www/html;
       }
```

Only to get 403 forbidden error. The `/home/tango/www/html/index.html` is generated by `tango` so I don't think I can put that in `/var/www/html/` writing where requires root permission.

The error log confirms the permission error:

```
2020/07/28 11:50:12 [error] 122769#0: *533 open() "/home/tango/www/html/index.html" failed (13: Permission denied), client: XXX.YYY.ZZZ.AAA, server: , request: "GET /diagcte HTTP/1.1", host: "my.org"
```

However, `ls -la /home/tango/www/html/index.html` shows:

`-rw-r--r--. 1 tango posixusers 212 Jul 28 11:33 /home/tb571/www/html/index.html`

So the `nginx` user should have read permission.

Anyways, can you help with serving a non-root static file through `nginx`?

Answer (score 0):

The parent directory of the file `nginx` is trying to access must also have suitable permissions, not just the file itself.  Typically a `/home` directory is not accessible to other users.

You'd need to do something like `chgrp -R nginx /home/tango ; chmod g+rx /home/tango`, but consider the security implications of this in your own setup.

Depending on your distro, SELinux could also be denying permission.  Try `audit2allow -a` to see if that is causing an issue.

However, it may be advisable to move the root somewhere else and give `tango` write access there, rather than giving `nginx` access to the `/home` directory.

Comment: Hi @tetech, I did the latter, moved the root to `/tmp/www/html/`. Although `index.html` exists in the new root, now the error log says `2020/07/28 12:10:30 [error] 129758#0: *538 open() "/tmp/www/html/index.html" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: XXX.YY server: , request: "GET /index.html HTTP/1.1", host: "my.org"`

What can I do now?

Comment: If the `nginx` config has been updated and it has been restarted, file permissions are OK, then it should work; SELinux may not apply to you but is sometimes overlooked, try `echo 0 > /selinux/enforce` to disable temporarily, then re-try.

Comment: `/tmp` is also a bad choice, since different users might have their own `/tmp` directories. You should use `/var/www/html`.

Comment: Hi @TeroKilkanen, I already mentioned-- a non-root user does not have write permission in `/var/www/html` directory.

Comment: Then you should use some other directory where you can assign appropriate permissions, but not `/tmp`.

Comment: Yeah, all users in my server use `/tmp` as their temporary directory. So, I don't think that is a bad choice for me.